# Disable the auto generated dropdown for belongs_to relations in Rails/ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have two models: UserDevice and UserInfo as follows (in schema.rb):

```
  create_table "user_devices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_info_id"
    t.string   "platform"
    t.string   "unique_id"
    t.string   "id_for_push"
    t.string   "last_ip"
    t.string   "unique_id_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  add_index "user_devices", ["user_info_id"], name: "index_user_devices_on_user_info_id", using: :btree

  create_table "user_infos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "google_unique_id"
    t.string "email"
    t.uuid   "user_id"
  end
```

Adding the UserDevice model to ActiveAdmin, A filter for UserInfo is automatically created and slows down load time significantly because it loads all the user_infos - see image.

**How do I remove this filter or change it to a simple textbox / lookup?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable filtering add

```
config.filters = false
```

to the page definition, where you want to disable filters.

To create a custom filter in AA you would use `filter`:

```
filter :user_info, as: :select, collection: -> { UserInfo.pluck(:id, :email) }
```

## EDIT

Adding a text filter to AA:

```
filter :user_info_email_cont, label: 'Preferences' # it will search by associated `user_infos` table, by column email.
```

You can also choose `user_info_email_eq` (to find exact match)
[Take a look](http://viget.com/extend/activeadmin-filters-unlocking-the-power-of-ransack) for more examples

(use `user_infos_xxx` if has_many, `user_info_xxx` if has one)

Comment: Thanks @andrey! both solutions "kind-of" worked. I'd like to change the dropdown to a textbox where I can enter the name / id of the user. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Thanks, @Andrey! Thanks for the link! I marked as the correct answer. PS I have a followup question here to which you will probably know the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373747/activeadmin-dropdown-too-big-when-editing-model-instance cheers! :)