# ActiveAdmin: Dropdown too big when editing model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have two models: `UserDevice` and `UserInfo` as follows (in schema.rb):

```
  create_table "user_devices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_info_id"
    t.string   "platform"
    t.string   "unique_id"
    t.string   "id_for_push"
    t.string   "last_ip"
    t.string   "unique_id_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  add_index "user_devices", ["user_info_id"], name: "index_user_devices_on_user_info_id", using: :btree

  create_table "user_infos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "google_unique_id"
    t.string "email"
    t.uuid   "user_id"
  end
```

When editing the user device it lets me choose between too many options. This both takes too long to load and is also impractical to choose from such a huge list - see image.

**How can I change this dropdown control to a more human input?**

[image]

Comment: how the going with this one man?

Comment: I'll check it out when I get back to the office.. Looks more complicated but nothing I can't handle! ;)

Comment: absolutely :) take your time

Comment: hey Nimo, just checking if the suggested solution worked for you

Comment: Thanks andrey! Did not get around to that yet! I promise to give you +1 as soon as I do :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Check out [chosen_rails gem](https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails).

Make sure to follow installation recommendations carefully (i.e. requiring js's, css's and so on).

Your `user_info` input will look something like this:

```
f.input :user_info,
  collection: -> { UserInfo.pluck(:id, :email) },
  input_html: { class: 'chosen-select' }
```

Here is an example as per docs:

```
f.association :user_info, 
  collection: UserInfo.pluck(:id, :email),
  include_blank: true,
  input_html: { class: 'chosen-select' }
```

But I do not remember if Formtastic has `f.association`.

You should try different compositions of these two examples.
What it would do, is you will start type `email` (you can pick any other attribute) and it will immediately pick only these, which are matching to already typed letters.