# ActiveAdmin Resource Form: Replacing belongs_to Select Input with Alternative format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

Is there a quick and easy method/library to replace an ActiveAdmin resource's belongs_to association (Formtastic) input that meets these requirements?

- It does not load every record from the table onto the page. That's the problem with the default select dropdown. If my Users table has 100k records, it has to render every record's `:name` and `:id` into the dropdown.
- It autocompletes or provides some AJAX-like feedback that I'm selecting an associated record that actually exists. A simple textbox where I must know the ID of the associated record is not sufficient.

I would hope that the resulting code would look like:

```
# in app/models/my_resource.rb
class MyResource
  belongs_to :user
end

# in app/admin/my_resource.rb
form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Details' do
    f.input :user, as: :something_convenient, plus_optional: :parameters_if_needed
  end
  f.actions
end
```

Comment: hey, did you find chosen-rails useful?

Comment: I haven't had the opportunity yet to take it for a test drive, but once I do I'll be sure to choose your answer or provide whatever feedback. Thanks for the quick answer to the question though.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is [chosen-rails](https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails) gem.

Some time ago I've answered few questions on the topic, so not to repeat stuff please see them for more details:

[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26925717/1772830)

[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373747/activeadmin-dropdown-too-big-when-editing-model-instance)